# Android alert dialog query

Tags: android

I have been working on android application and I have got stuck at a point.

I have a method which shows a progress dialog to the user. Then after the code has run I am showing an alert dialog.

Here I have got stuck. The progress dialog is not showing when method calls.

Code:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NameOfYourActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

Thanks

Comment: hey dude I fixed your spelling and formatting. If you take a while to try and get the spelling and english looking better then people will be more likely to spend time helping you with your answer.

Comment: Is the name of your activity `NameOfYourActivity`? I think this might be your problem. You need to change that bit to the actual class name of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

put a title or try with null

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NameOfYourActivity.this, "Title", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NameOfYourActivity.this, null, "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the UI thread do next? Dialog showing code won't work until the UI thread returns from the current method - as in all GUI systems, window drawing logic is queued and invoked from the message loop. So if you show the dialog and then immediately start the loading, the dialog won't get a chance to show.

For one thing, doing lengthy loading in the UI thread is universally considered a bad design. I'd advise you to move the loading into either Thread or AsyncTask. But as a first step, you can insert a trip to the message loop between show() and the rest, like this:

```
ProgressDialog.show()
new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
public void run()
{
    //Rest of the method
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

this line just create the dialog object

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NameOfYourActivity.this, "", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

after this call

```
progressDialog.show();
```